# Convert date in MySQL to yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: mysql, date

I have a DB where the dates are stored as varchar mm/dd/yyy (12/10/2022) But I can't figure out how to convert them to yyyy-mm-dd (2022-12-10 or 2022/12/10)

This doesn't work
SELECT DATE_FORMAT("06/15/2022", "%Y-%m-%d");

P.S. I also want to issue a SQL command to change all the dates in the DB

Comment: You need [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? What's the point in storing dates as strings, and not as dates?

Comment: Could you please suggest which database management system you are using?

Comment: *convert them to yyyy-mm-dd* Do you want to convert the data in-place (saving varchar datatype)?

Comment: If you want to store date in the column, I would recommend using the [DATE type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a string to a date with the function str_to_date():

`select str_to_date('12/10/2022',"%m/%d/%Y");`

https://www.w3schools.com/Sql/func_mysql_str_to_date.asp